# How web programs can make changes to a Linux applications?

Tags: php, python, web

How this web programming works?

For example, we have a Linux application running on a server i.e “bind”.

How do we create a Web GUI to manage that bind server?

For example, if we add a zone through the GUI, that zone should be registered in the bind’s config file. I just want to how stuff works. How connection works, How an apache server can make modifications to application’s config file?

Any hints would be really appreciated.

Comment: What do you do if you want to manually register a zone in bind? Describe it, step by step. Then you will know how to write your software.

Comment: @ArturR.Czechowski, thank you for your suggestion (y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php can natively work with files on the file system so long as the user running service thread has permissions to the file you want to change. It's pretty easy to do.

```
$myFile = "/var/config.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile,'w');
```

A better way for two applications to interact is through a database though. Having the web application writing to a config table that the console app reads and uses.